# capturing a result in a variable

Tags: python, function, csv

I am just getting my head around functions in Python (only been learning Python for 6 months) and I'm stuck on some code which is not working. It says total is not defined, nameerror. Reading through some posts I think I need to store total in a variable but I don't know where. Can you do this in the return statement? Not sure where to define total to make it global.

It's a program with several tasks. I'm also struggling with storing a table into a csv file. Here is the code.

```
import csv

def set_values():
    ans1 = float(input('Please enter the first number: '))

    ans2 = float(input('Please enter the second number: '))

    ans3 = float(input('Please enter the third number: '))

    levels = int(input('Please set the amount of levels between 5 and 10: '))


    return (ans1, ans2, ans3, levels) 


def display_model_values(ans1, ans2, ans3, levels):
    print('The outcome for model 1 is ',ans1)
    print('The outcome for model 2 is ',ans2)
    print('The outcome for model 3 is ',ans3)
    print('The number of levels are ',levels)


def run_model(ans1, ans2, ans3, levels):
    total = ans1+ans2+ans3
    print ("\t","Level","\t","Answer 1","\t","Answer 2","\t","Answer 3","\t","Total")
    for i in range (0,levels+1):
        print("\t",i,"\t\t",ans1,"\t\t",ans2,"\t\t",ans3,"\t\t",total)
        result1 =ans2*ans3
        result2 = ans2/ans1
        total = ans1+result1+result2
    return (i,result1, result2, total)


def export_data(ans1,ans2,ans3,total):
    table = [ans1, ans2, ans3,total]

    nameoffile = input('what would you like to call the filename')
    nameoffile = open(nameoffile+".csv","w")
    csv_file_ref = csv.writer(nameoffile)
    csv_file_ref.writerow(table)
    nameoffile.close()

##    with open(nameoffile+'.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
##        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
##        writer.writerow(r) for r in table]




choice = ''
count = 0
while choice != 'q':
    print('Main Menu')
    print ('1)Set Model Values')
    print ('2)Display Model Values')
    print ('3)Run Model')
    print ('4)Export Data')
    print ('Q)Quit')
    choice = input('Please Enter Choice')


    if choice =='1':
        ans1, ans2, ans3, levels = set_values()
        count = count +1

    elif choice == '2':
        if count < 1:
           print ('you need to choose option 1 first')
        else:
            display_model_values(ans1,ans2,ans3,levels)


    elif choice =='3':
        if count < 1:
            print('you need to choose option 1 first')
        else:
            run_model(ans1,ans2,ans3,levels)

    elif choice =='4':
        if count < 1:
           print ('you need to choose option 1 first')
        else:
            export_data(ans1,ans2,ans3,total)

    elif choice == 'Q':
            break
    else:
        print('not an option')
```

Comment: Please post the traceback of the `NameError` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your total is defined only within the function `run_model`. When that function returns, you cannot reference `total` again, since its gone [out of scope](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_scope_and_namespaces.html). The variable is now "unbound", and that is exactly what Python is telling you when it says that the name `total` is not defined. It was defined once, somewhere, but it's long gone.

A simple change to your code would be to have total calculated again, inside the body of the export function, as here:

```
def export_data(ans1,ans2,ans3):
    total = ans1 + ans2 + ans3  # total is available inside of export_data
    table = [ans1, ans2, ans3,total]

    nameoffile = input('what would you like to call the filename')
    nameoffile = open(nameoffile+".csv","w")
    csv_file_ref = csv.writer(nameoffile)
    csv_file_ref.writerow(table)
    nameoffile.close()
```

These should make your code work.

Comment: Thank you, however the error is in Line 87 which is in the elif choice ==4

Comment: Not working yet, sorry. I did add the above. I'm not getting how total is unbound as I did return it. Maybe I don't understand what return actually does?

Comment: @LisaG sorry, there was a small mistake in the function signature above. Instead of `export_data(ans1, ans2, ans3, total)` it should've read `export_data(ans1, ans2, ans3)`. Code is now edited

Comment: Many thanks Daniel that worked! Now I just need to export the correct values! I'll post another question later.

Comment: OK, great. In this case you can consider accepting the answer, so other users know your problem is solved. Good luck!

Comment: I clicked the tick to accept the answer and now I just need to find out how to do an upvote! First time user!

Answer (score 1):

On line 83, you are sending the variable `total` to the function export_data(ans1,ans2,ans3,total) which is not defined within your while loop. Assuming that your total is `ans1+ans2+ans3` before sending the value,
add the line,

```
total = ans1+ans2+ans3
```

That should solve the problem.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\test.py", line 87, in <module>
    export_data(ans1,ans2,ans3,total)
NameError: name 'total' is not defined

Comment: @LisaG, Thanks!  Can you please upvote my answer and accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure that you mean upvote? The code is not working still

Answer (score 0):

def export_data(ans1,ans2,ans3):
    total = ans1 + ans2 + ans3  # total is available inside of export_data
    table = [ans1, ans2, ans3,total]

```
nameoffile = input('what would you like to call the filename')
nameoffile = open(nameoffile+".csv","w")
csv_file_ref = csv.writer(nameoffile)
csv_file_ref.writerow(table)
nameoffile.close()
```

Now it exports and there is no error on total